# Adding Alt Text Automatically to all images without JS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

How can i set the alt atribute = the filename of an image tag in asp.net automatically without using javascript?

```
<img src="/a/b/c/xxx.jpg" />
```

to

```
<img src="/a/b/c/xxx.jpg" alt="xxx.jpg" />
```

I tought maybe something like a rewrite module on IIS? Or maybe somehow change the base Image class to emit different html?

Any ideias?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to add the `runat="server"` attribute to your img tags, then in your code behind you can loop through the list of controls on your page and for all the `img` tags, update the `alt` attribute.  I wrote this without testing so there may be some minor tweaks required.

```
private void UpdateImgTags<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection)
where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {

        if (control is T)  {
            string filename = (T)control.Attributes["src"];
            filename = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
            (T)control.Attributes.Add("alt",filename);
        }
    }
}
```

To call the method:

```
UpdateImgTags<HtmlImage>(Page.Controls)
```

Comment: Sounds nice, i'll try it brb

Comment: Nice idea but i ended up using a HttpModule (had no idea they were so easy to make) and replacing the raw contents, it's for a very low traffic site so it's ok.